# Dialogflow getting username from Gmail account in inline editor

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a Dialogflow inline, where when welcome intent is executed I need to call `agent.add()` so it replies with something like

> Hello (username)!

This username is not that the user writes but it's the profile name that he has logged in to the device

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the user's name, you need to request permission from the user. So it usually isn't available as part of the welcoming Intent (at least not the first time they talk to your Action). You need to do one of two things:

- Request [user information](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers#user_information) which includes the user name. Once you have requested this information, you can [save it](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data#saving_data_across_conversations) so you'll get it the next time the user connects.
- Ask the user to [sign in](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/gsi-concept-guide). Once they have done so, you'll get an identity token with each request that includes the user's information